# How can i define a column as tinyint(4) using sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to define my table as

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `o_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `m_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `o_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `client_id` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `set_id` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `s1` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `s2` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `s3` tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `review` varchar(2045) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `br_o_id_idx` (`order_id`),
  KEY `br_date_idx` (`created_at`),
  KEY `br_on_idx` (`operator_name`),
  KEY `br_mn_idx` (`merchant_name`)
)
```

but as i am looking on sequelize documentation , it does not have support for tiny int with its size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the lack of `ZERO_FILL` in your table definition, I suspect `tinyint(4)` probably does not do what you think it does. From [11.2.5 Numeric Type Attributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html):

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type.
>
> ...
>
> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column.
>
> ...
>
> For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.

I'm not sure if other RDBMSs treat the number in parens differently, but from perusing the [sequelize source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/data-types.js) it looks like they're under the same, incorrect, impression you are.

That being said, the important part of your schema, being that you want to store those fields as `TINYINT`s (using only a byte of storage to contain values between 0-255), is sadly not available in the Sequelize DataTypes. I might suggest opening a PR to add it...

On the other hand, if you really are looking for the ZEROFILL functionality, and need to specify that *display width* of 4, you could do something like `Sequelize.INTEGER(4).ZEROFILL`, but obviously, that would be pretty wasteful of space in your DB.

Comment: so how it actually matters. I just want to limit my value between 0-255 because i have a column in my db as tinyint . it doesn't matter weather i am filling it with 0 or not

Comment: That's my point; the number in parenthesis after an integer type *doesn't* do that. And since the `sequelize` authors don't provide the correct way to do what you want, you can't do it. You might try using the [sequelize boolean](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/data-types.js#L377) type to make a `tinyint` field in your schema, but I imagine that would wreak havoc with the way the ORM handles that type JS side.

Comment: Actually, thinking about how `sequelize` handles this, if you're saying that you're creating the schema outside of sequelize, so it already is a tinyint, you could use `min` and `max` [validations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#validations) to get what you want, and just tell sequelize that it's an integer field.

Comment: Sequelize.INTEGER(4).ZEROFILL , <-- this thing helped me!

Comment: Hi, just to add more info. This works type: DataTypes.TINYINT(4).ZEROFILL

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL, the Sequelize.BOOLEAN data type maps to TINYINT(1). See

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/data-types.js#L397

and

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/datatypes/

As noted by @user866762, the number in parentheses only affects how the data is displayed, not how it is stored. So, TINYINT(1) vs. TINYINT(4) should have no effect on your data.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that you have `tinyint unsigned` and I don't believe you can add the UNSIGNED flag to the Sequelize.BOOLEAN type. If you really need values between 128 and 255, you may be forced to use Sequelize.INTEGER...  You could always create the table with `tinyint unsigned` fields and use the Sequelize.INTEGER type in your model along with validation to ensure the value stays between 0 and 255. However, you wouldn't be able to `sync()` your model to the database.

Comment: I don't need a BOOLEAN type

Comment: I know you don't need a BOOLEAN type. If you look at the docs and the code that I linked to, you'll see that Sequelize translates BOOLEAN to TINYINT for MySQL. It's the only way to effectively use TINYINT with Sequelize. You're only other option is to use INTEGER along with validations, as I previously stated.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, we define with Sequelize: `DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED` while database column is defined with `TINYINT(1)` type.